# Can an animal messenger wait around to deliver its message?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*animal messenger*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-messenger) spell allows you to send an animal messenger to a specified location to deliver a message to a specified individual.  What happens if the animal arrives at its destination and the intended recipient isn't there (nor anyone matching their description)?  Can the messenger wait around (as long as the spell is active) until the intended recipient shows up, or does the spell expire immediately without the message being delivered?  Is there an official answer to this?

Comment: Is my answer good enough for the green check? Are there any improvements you would like to see?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this sooner.  To answer your question: I thought both responses presented their arguments well (and I don't think Odo's deserved to be downvoted), but since neither of them cites any official rulings, it comes down to a matter of opinion and personal interpretation.  Therefore it didn't feel right to me to choose either of them as the "best" answer.

Comment: I upvoted Odo's answer, I thought it was well reasoned. Neither of our answers cited official *rulings* because there no official rulings on the matter. We did however cite official *rules* which is the closest thing to an official answer that is possible. I've edited my question to more directly answer your last question. Maybe its good enough now?

Comment: It's not that your answer wasn't "good enough"; it's just that I don't feel comfortable saying that it's definitively *better* than Odo's (since in the absence of an official ruling, it comes down to opinion).  I appreciate you taking the time, and I'm sorry to disappoint you, but rest assured that it's not due to any shortcomings on your part.

Answer (score 7):

*There are no official rulings on this spell, so the best we can do it make one using the rules we have.*

[*Animal messenger*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-messenger) requires two things:

> You specify a **location**, which you must have visited, and a **recipient** who matches a general description, such as "a man or woman dressed in the uniform of the town guard" or "a red-haired dwarf wearing a pointed hat."

The description continues:

> If the messenger doesn't reach its **destination** before the spell ends, the message is lost, and the beast makes its way back to where you cast this spell.

I would argue that the destination here is *both the location and recipient*. You have told the animal where to go and who to look for, the message has not reached its destination until it has arrived at the recipient, so this is covered in the spell description’s use of “destination”. So the animal may continue to “travel” to its destination, the recipient, in the given location until the spell ends.

Then, if not found, the message is lost when the spell ends and the animal returns.